# Bash Shell variable substitution issue

Tags: bash, shell

I've defined a variable to be substituted in BASH which looks like this

```
EXPORT_FLT_2="<ngc_filter_configuration><ngc_filters><ngc_filter>ngc_filter_operator   operator='and'><ngc_filter_term type='ip' value='192.168.175.99'/><ngc_filter_term type='ip' value='72.32.127.138'/></ngc_filter_operator></ngc_filter></ngc_filters></ngc_filter_configuration>";
```

I now want to use this variable in my shell script which looks like

```
. /mnt/.kumara/automation/exportcli.cfg
${PA_HOME}/exportcli -v -1:-1:-1:-1 0x1A2B3C4D $TFA_TRACE_FILE $TFA_ip $TFA_ifn   $TFA_ST $TFA_ET "$1" &> /dev/null 
md5sum ${TFA_TRACE_FILE}1.cap | cut -d' ' -f1
rm ${TFA_TRACE_FILE}1.cap
```

All the variables being used except for "$1" are defined in the exportcli.cfg file
Now after executing the script like

```
$./export.sh "$EXPORT_FLT_2"
```

Insted of the actual substitution of the variable I see no parameters being passed. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: This is strange. Can you just print $1 at the beginning and/or execute the shell script with `sh -x`? That will give you hints.

Comment: How do you know that no parameter is being passed?  Do you get an error message?  In that case, can you post it?  In case your exportcli program tries to report an error on stdout instead of stderr, can you remove the >/dev/null?

Comment: Useing `-x` I got the following result `++ . /mnt/.kumara/automation/exportcli.cfg
+++ TFA_ST=1312464957000...<all the remaining substitutions>
+++ EXPORT_FLT_2='<ngc_filter_configuration><ngc_filters><ngc_filter><ngc_filter_operator operator='\''and'\''><ngc_filter_term type='\''ip'\'' value='\''192.168.175.99'\''/><ngc_filter_term type='\''ip'\'' value='\''72.32.127.138'\''/></ngc_filter_operator></ngc_filter></ngc_filters></ngc_filter_configuration>'
++ echo` But `echo $1` results in a blank

Comment: It would be better if you used the "edit" button underneath your main post, that allows better formatting than the comments do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't immediately spot the error here, but here's what I'd try.

1: run `echo $EXPORT_FLT_2` in your shell to confirm that the variable you've defined is actually defined.

2: Stick `echo $1` at various points in your export.sh script in turn, starting at the top.  See if the variable gets mangled somewhere.

3: run `sh -x export.sh "$EXPORT_FLT_2"` to see what the script actually executes on each step.

This should help pinpont more accurately what's happening and where the error originates.

**Update**

It seems the EXPORT_FLT_2 variable is defined in you config file, not in your shell.  Try changing `$1` in your script to `${!1}` and calling your script as

```
$ ./export.sh EXPORT_FLT_2
```

(note, no $ decoration on the variable name).

Comment: Could you update your question with this output, and put it in a code block?  That would make it easier to read.

Comment: But if I parse this correctly, it seems that EXPORT_FLT_2 is defined in the exportcli.cfg file, as @qiaomuf and myself touched on in his answer.

Comment: I tried using all the tricks of debugging you mentined in your answer. However even tough I can see the variable actually being defined in `-x` the `echo $1` results in a blank, when I run `sh -x $./export.sh "$EXPORT_FLT_2"` . My guess is that there might be some kind of an error in the definition in the exportcli.cfg file...but not sure :(

Comment: `++ . /mnt/.kumara/automation/exportcli.cfg +++ TFA_ST=1312464957000...<all the remaining substitutions> +++ EXPORT_FLT_2='<ngc_filter_configuration><ngc_filters><ngc_filter><ngc_filter_ope‌​rator operator='\''and'\''><ngc_filter_term type='\''ip'\'' value='\''192.168.175.99'\''/><ngc_filter_term type='\''ip'\'' value='\''72.32.127.138'\''/></ngc_filter_operator></ngc_filter></ngc_filters></‌​ngc_filter_configuration>' ++ echo`

Comment: Did you see the update to my answer?  EXPORT_FTL_2 is apparently not defined in the shell you use to start your export.sh script.  So sticking $EXPORT_FTL_2 on the command line will expand it to "" before your script starts, and $1 will be empty.  Use EXPORT_FTL_2 without the $ on the command line, and use the ${!1} trick in your script to tell bash that there is a level of indirection there.

Comment: OK..thanks a lot, this did work !! I now realize the issue was due to indirection :)